# How change the width of widget LinkedIn Company Insider to embed on web site?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I use the code (an example) `<script type="IN/CompanyInsider" data-id="xxx"></script>` to display box on web site but i need to change the width of widget because it's too large. I tried to change property css "width" of iframe but it's no possible...

Someone can help me?
Thanks